# How to change instance variable after initialisation?

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of initialiser. I have created an instance of SurveyQuestion (i.e. cheeseQuestion) below.

However, after creation, I want to change the 'var text: String' to "what kind of cheese do you like"? Could someone please kindly tell me how it could be done?

```
class SurveyQuestion{
    var text: String
    var response: String?
    init(text: String){
        self.text = text;
    }
    func ask(){
        print(text)
    }
}

let cheeseQuestion = SurveyQuestion(text: "do you like cheese?")
cheeseQuestion.ask()
cheeseQuestion.response = "yes, i do like cheese"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cheeseQuestion.text = "What kind of cheese do you like?"
```

Nothing special.